# Usage of のに contrary to what I expected

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

The meaning of のに is "despite", "although".

But in the sentence, it seems to have another role. Could you explain?

Context: another character wants to join the team consisting of the protagonist and Aqua.

> 俺はここ二回のカエルと戦いで、どうもこの女神、ちっとも使えないんじゃないかと疑っているのだ。
> はっきり言って、アクア一人でも厄介**なのに**これ以上問題児は。。。
>
> Our recent battles with the Giant Toads had left me doubting whether
> this goddess was going to be any help to me at all. To be blunt, Aqua
> was a liability all by herself. To take on another problem child ...

Comment: What's the rest of the sentence? How do you get "to take on ..."?

Comment: it comes from two things but I may be mistaken: first the context that I indicated just before the sentence, and the expression これ以上. The Japanese sentence is truncated as such, the rest has been left to the reader to guess. The story goes on with the protagonist trying (unsucessfully) to leave the two other characters.

Comment: Couldn't this just be な + nominalizer の + adverbial に? That is, "Aqua being a problematic thing..." (Not that I'm incredibly confident in this answer, but it seems possible)

Comment: @Sam that is an interesting idea, but what is the role and meaning of に here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

のに is used in the situations below.

> 簡単なのにできない。 It is easy, but I cannot do that.

> 勉強するのに必要です。= 勉強する**ために**必要です。 This is necessary to study.

> メールしてねって言ったのに。。。 I told you to email me, but...  (You did NOT do so. I am angry or not satisfied.)

> 簡単なはずなのに。。。 This is easy, but...  This implies "Why can't you do this although this is so easy!?"

The last case is close to your case.

> はっきり言って、アクア一人でも厄介なのにこれ以上問題児は。。。

> アクア一人でも厄介なのに。。。　"Aqua is a problem person I barely handle, but..."
> This implies that "I cannot handle another problem person anymore!!"

So, He can say just "アクア一人でも厄介なのに。。。", but he said more words to show his complaint clearly. 
"これ以上問題児は。。。" = "another problem person..."
He didn't have to say words after "厄介なのに", but he said so.

If he said more clearly, he would say "アクア一人でも厄介なのに、これ以上問題児が増えるのはごめんだ。